# Issue with real-time log inspecting piping tail, grep and cut

Tags: grep, logs, tail, cut

I have to inspect a growing log in real time, and I found an issue that makes me *miss* some lines (I can't understand exactly what lines) using `tail -f` or `tailf`, `grep` and `cut`.

I use `grep` because I want to filter lines containing a specific word, and then `cut -c -NUM` because some lines are very long and I don't want them to wrap in my terminal window.

Here is a minimal example, in which I'm watching a sample log made of *"Nth line"* lines, filtering for word *"line"*, missing all lines in this case (obviously `^C` is me killing the process):

```
$ tail -n 3 -f log

13th line
14th line
15th line
^C

$ tail -n 3 -f log | grep --color=never 'line'

13th line
14th line
15th line
^C

$ echo $COLUMNS

100

$ tail -n 3 -f log | grep --color=never 'line' | cut -c -$COLUMNS

^C
```

Note that this issue occours **only with `tail -f` (or `tailf`), `grep` and `cut` combined**. If I do not use `grep` in the middle, or `cut` at the end of the pipe, there's no missing line. If I replace `tail -f` with `tail` or `cat`, no problem. You can see every possible case in [this longer example](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=9YJG3eAk).

I'm on Ubuntu 13.04, *GNU coreutils* (`tail`, `cut`) version 8.20 and *GNU grep* 2.14.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with your example is buffering between `grep` and `cut`. The data will only by passed along the pipe when the buffer is full (4kB on my system).

Try adding `--line-buffered` to `grep` to have it flush the buffer after each line.

Comment: Thank you very much! So `grep` uses a buffer only when piped into another command?

Comment: The buffering is standard behavior of libc, it's not specific to `grep`. By default output to a terminal is line buffered, and gets flushed every line. Otherwise, the output is fully buffered. This includes piping to another command, redirecting output to a file and/or processes that are not attached to a terminal (e.g. cron jobs).

Comment: I actually see this issue just with cut, and not grep at all.  is there another solution if just using a pipe with cut?